# How to download video with JW Player blob url?

Tags: firefox, video, download

I am looking for a solution for downloading videos embedded using JW Player Blobs in web pages.

I have seen some answers for twitter/vimeo/other blob situations but not seen an answer to JW Player blobs.

As an example of a webpage with an embedded JW Player blob we can use this page https://product.soundstrue.com/power-of-awareness/tara-brach-compassion/

in Firefox I play the video and rightclick to View Page Info. 
Click Media tab and I see this link to the video blob:https://product.soundstrue.com/d8980d59-b8eb-45c7-936e-1553bff0946f

I tried the previously posted suggestions but could not find a way to download the video.

Any solutions?
thanks for your time and help
regards
Per Norrgren

Comment: Did you try `youtube-dl`? This may already help.

Comment: Have you tried Firefox add-ons? Open Tools in the menu and click add-ons.

Comment: thanks. tried the youtube-dl and it gives error as it is not a direct link:

youtube-dl https://product.soundstrue.com/d8980d59-b8eb-45c7-936e-1553bff0946f
[generic] d8980d59-b8eb-45c7-936e-1553bff0946f: Requesting header
WARNING: Could not send HEAD request to https://product.soundstrue.com/d8980d59-b8eb-45c7-936e-1553bff0946f: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
[generic] d8980d59-b8eb-45c7-936e-1553bff0946f: Downloading webpage
ERROR: Unable to download webpage: HTTP Error 404: Not Found (caused by HTTPError()); please report this issue on https://yt-dl.org/bug . Make sure you are us

Comment: re: "Have you tried Firefox add-ons? Open Tools in the menu and click add-ons"  what addons are you thinking of that you have used for JW Blob downloads?  all the best. Per Norrgren

Answer (score 0):

**Download JW Player Videos**

Updated December 18, 2019

> *Using View Page Info In FireFox*
>   
> Stream the video you want to download
>   
> Right click on the page
>   
> Select ‘View Page Info’

Firefox opens a dialogue box

> Go to ‘Media’
>   
> Scroll down and find the video file in the list
>   
> Check the video format in ‘Type’ column
>   
> Select the file and click on ‘Save As’

Using this, the video should start the download to your local hard drive.
[How To Download JW player Videos](https://silicophilic.com/how-to-download-jw-player-videos/)

Also Google Chrome, and plug-ins for Firefox are listed there.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Thank you, that is correct and works when the media is a file.   in this case the question relates to when the media is a blob  as in the example I posted in the quesiton  "blob:https://product.soundstrue.com/d8980d59-b8eb-45c7-936e-1553bff0946f"  if you follow this link you get a page not found.  yes, JW Player palys the blob fine in the embedded player on the page (see the other link in the question).   Anyone seen or done this before, please?